# C++, Passing an object as a parameter in anothers object constructor

Tags: c++, class, object

I have 3 classes in 3 files.

- Fecha.h
- Horario.h
- Recordatorio.h

I want to be able to create a new Recordatorio class that has an Fecha and Horario class inside.

This is the function i have in main:

```
Recordatorio recordatorio(Fecha(5, 10), Horario(9, 0), "Clase Algo2");
```

Note: Fecha(5,10) and Horario(9,10) works just fine.

This is the code i have in my Recordatorio.cpp:

```
#include "Recordatorio.h"
#include "Fecha.h"
#include "Horario.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Recordatorio::Recordatorio(Fecha fecha, Horario horario, string mensaje){
    fecha_ = fecha;
    horario_ = horario;
    mensaje_ = mensaje;
}

void Recordatorio::mensaje(){
    cout << mensaje_ << endl;
}
```

And this in my Recordatorio.h:

```
#ifndef RECORDATORIO_H
#define RECORDATORIO_H
#include "Fecha.h"
#include "Horario.h"
#include <string>

class Recordatorio
{
    public:
        Recordatorio(Fecha fecha, Horario horario, std::string mensaje);
        void mensaje();

    private:
        Fecha fecha_;
        Horario horario_;
        std::string mensaje_;

};

#endif // RECORDATORIO_H
```

The error im getting in Recordatorio.cpp is the following:

error: no matching function for call to 'Fecha::Fecha()'

Edit: Fecha.h

```
#ifndef FECHA_H
#define FECHA_H

using uint = unsigned int;

class Fecha{
    public:
        Fecha(uint mes,uint dia);
        uint mes();
        uint dia();
    void incrementar_dia();
    private:
        uint mes_;
        uint dia_;
};

#endif // FECHA_H
```

Fecha.cpp

```
#include "Fecha.h"

uint dias_en_mes(uint mes) {
    uint dias[] = {
        // ene, feb, mar, abr, may, jun
        31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30,
        // jul, ago, sep, oct, nov, dic
        31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
    };
    return dias[mes - 1];
}

uint Fecha::mes() {
    return mes_;
}

uint Fecha::dia() {
    return dia_;
}

Fecha::Fecha(uint dia, uint mes){
    dia_ = dia;
    mes_ = mes;
}

void Fecha::incrementar_dia(){
    uint maximo_dia_mes = dias_en_mes(mes_);
    if (dia_ < maximo_dia_mes){
        dia_++;
    } else {
        dia_ = 1;
        if (mes_ != 12){
            mes_++;
        } else {
            mes_ = 1;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Horario.h:

```
#ifndef HORARIO_H
#define HORARIO_H

using uint = unsigned int;

class Horario
{
    public:
        Horario(uint hora, uint min);
        uint hora();
        uint min();
    private:
        uint hora_;
        uint min_;
};

#endif // HORARIO_H
```

Horario.cpp:

```
#include "Horario.h"

using uint = unsigned int;

Horario::Horario(uint hora, uint min){
    hora_ = hora;
    min_ = min;
}

uint Horario::hora() {
    return hora_;
}

uint Horario::min() {
    return min_;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for the class Fecha? From the error message, I would assume it is not default-constructible.

Comment: Use an initialization list for your constructor, then it doesn't need to be default constructable.

Comment: Edited. @PeteFordham please could you post an example?

Comment: Edited, and added the two classes @Philipp Claßen

Comment: You have an answer, I'll just add that for memory efficient pass your objects as const references, e.g. `Recordatorio(const Fecha & fecha, const Horario & horario, const string & mensaje)`. This saves a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Recordatorio::Recordatorio(Fecha fecha, Horario horario, string mensaje) :
    fecha_(fecha),
    horario_(horario),
    mensaje_(mensaje) {
}
```

This will now use the default copy constructor for your classes rather than constructing an empty object then assigning it.